# Traffic handling capacity for 1 EC2 instance for t3.2xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

Protocol exchange between phone server and IOT device(inter regional). say there are 100000 users and each are requesting or using 12 - 20 times a day may be approximately at the same time(protocols are very small less than 1 KB), so I need to create instances for protocol exchange and auto scaling, each transfer is stored as a log and a backup up-to 1000 GB

here is my instances purchasing idea user -> Route53 -> Elastic Beamstalk - > I am -> RDS -> S3 -> cloud front

I need the traffic handling capacity for 1 EC2 instance for t3.2xlarge - vCPU's 8 - Memory - 32GB i.e I need to know how many request at a time it can handle to estimate the cost by calculating how many EC2 instances I'll be using and also need someone to rectify my instance purchase if any

Comment: Unfortunately this is something you need to benchmark yourself, as every application is different. Rather than use EC2 instances you should consider [AWS Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/), which is made for receiving and distributing streaming data. EC2 instances do the actual processing, but you have more reliability and it's easier to scale.

Comment: this is kinda design and capacity planing type of question, either you have test your use case your own or check with AWS advance service.